# Should I use a mixed effects model or something simpler?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, dag

I'm running a study in which participants rate various items using 4 different scales, one of which is the dependent variable (all 0-100). There are 8 items in total. The hypothesis I want to test is that one of the independent variables, call it IV1, is the strongest predictor.

What is the simplest sort of analysis to conduct here?

Initially, I had thought of running a mixed effects model, with `item` as a random effect, but a colleague suggested that with only 8 items, that would basically be pointless (like trying to estimate the variability in height based on only 8 people).

Should I just run a mixed effects model with a random intercept for participant? So, something like the following:

`lmer(DV ~ 1 + IV1 + IV2 + IV3 + item + (1|Participant)`

Alternatively, would it be better to use something like DAGs to test my hypothesis?

Answer (score 1):

When you measure a variable using a scale, one thing you could do is to summarize the scale using factor analysis and use factor score as the independent variable instead of the raw score items. Assuming each scale is unidimensional (meaning only results in only 1 latent factor), then you can simple run a linear regression to examine the effect size of each factor, as there will only be 1 row for each of your participant in your data.

Structural equation modeling could be another solution, where the latent structure and the fixed effects are fit together.

Comment: Thanks. That's very helpful. What's the drawback of just using the raw scores and running the mixed effects model I've specified above?